# Unable to set Category Blog layout; (read-only) Link stuck to 'layout=ja_purity_iv:new'

Tags: layout

Created a new website using Joomla v4 (latest version). Quickly checked out the Purity IV template (still installed), then decided to use the Cassiopeia template.

The problem is that the Category Blog pages are still using the Purity IV layout (I don't think I've seen this issue at other places). This becomes apparent looking at the Menu Items for Category Blogs, which show a Link like this:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=ja_purity_iv:new&id=30
```

(note the 'layout=ja_purity_iv:new' variable)

So I checked everything that I could think of:

- System -> Global Configuration -> Articles

  - Category: Choose a Layout: Blog
- Content -> Categories: "Bike Life"

  - Options: Layout: Use Global
- Menu: Main Menu EN: "Bike Life"

  - Template Style: Use Default
  - Blog Layout: Select Layout Blog: Default

All fine.

I also tried changing these four settings, but nothing changes in how the page is displayed. So whatever sets this 'layout' variable overrules everything that I could find in the Joomla administrator GUI.

Where/how is/was this variable set?